# Loopback Mysql connector custom query result to field value

Tags: mysql, loopback

I use Loopback 3 with Mysql. We have dynamic datamodel use. For example UserAnswers containing type like 'admin' or 'user'. I want to add count of answers to countOfAnswers field for types.

Like:
type 'admin' has 5 answers.
type 'user' has 3 answers.

I need to count type of answers before save to get current index for answers. Like `'Select * from UserAnswers where type = "admin"'`and insert it to field value.

What is the best way to do counting or custom sql. Operation hook mayby? Or could I use custom field defination in model?

Answer (score 0):

LoopBack provides `count` endpoint out of the box. Just create `UserAnswers` model mapped to your database table and then make the following request:

```
GET /api/UserAnswers/count?where[type]=admin
```

Learn more in LoopBack docs here: [Get instance count](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/PersistedModel-REST-API.html#get-instance-count).

---

Regarding custom SQL queries: it is possible to execute arbitrary SQL query by calling `myModel.dataSource.connector.execute`, see the docs: [Executing native SQL](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Executing-native-SQL.html).